# Using homebrew installed SDL2 with Xcode

Tags: homebrew, sdl-2

I have installed SDL2 using Homebrew but now I don't know how to make sure Xcode can use it! I imported the created library and added it to the build phases tab of my project. But when I try to build I get the error 'SDL2/SDL.h' not found

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To be able to use SDL2 on Xcode you must set two things (which are required for SDL in general):

- where to find header files (so that Clang can compile with `-Iheader/path`)
- where to find the .dylib to link it to the project (since with brew you don't have a real `.framework`)

To know the correct paths you should invoke `sdl2-config --cflags` and `sdl2-config --libs`. On my system these produce:

```
:~jack$ /usr/local/bin/sdl2-config --cflags
-I/usr/local/include/SDL2 -I/usr/X11R6/include -D_THREAD_SAFE

:~jack$ /usr/local/bin/sdl2-config --libs
-L/usr/local/lib -lSDL2
```

Now just paste the first one into `other C flags` and the other one into `other linker flags` field of your project and you are ready to go.

You could set them up in the correct fields, which is `Header Search Paths` for `-I` and `Library Search Path` for `-l` but the result will be the same.

Comment: Sorry been really busy so I couldn't respond! Thanks for the answer a few questions though when I add the paths to other C flags and other linker flags I can access SDL but is it not nested like `#include <SDL2/SDL.h>` How can I make sure this works? And also what paths should I put into header search paths and library search paths if I wanted to do it the correct way? Because I tried doing it but didn't get it to work just yet.

Comment: Oh and also how do I get this to work with SDL_ttf as well? Because I can't find it! The nesting of SDL2/SDL.h and using the correct field worked out though thanks!

Comment: Ok nevermind I just made a few mistakes sorry! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Just a side note, if you add only the header and lib directories to your project's `Headr Search Paths` and `Library Search Paths`, you will get error, respectively, because in order to Xcode the use those libraries, you need to tell Xcode that, for example, use `-lSDL2` library, so I advise you to use the first method that the above answer provides.

Answer (score 4):

1. Install installed homebrew from https://brew.sh
2. Type in terminal `brew install sdl2`
3. Then show the path of framework (in xCode select project file >> build settings >> header search paths) and using cmd+shift+g type /usr/local/include
4. In 'General' 'Frameworks & Libraries' put libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib (its here /usr/local/Cellar/sdl2/2.0.14_1/lib)
5. And most important check 'Disable Library Validations' in 'Signing & Capabilities'

After these steps code started to work for me.

Comment: Don't duplicate your answers. If you (or someone else) decide to update/modify it later, you'll have to go over ever single one. I suggest posting it once, then posting a link in comments of the other question.

Answer (score 1):

1. brew search sdl2
2. brew install sdl2 sdl2_image sdl2_mixer sdl2_net sdl2_ttf
3. config xcode Build Settings --> All --> Search Paths --> Header Serch Paths
   --> /usr/local/include
4. config Xcode General ->add Frameworks and Libraries --> libSDL2-2.0.0.dylib
5. test your code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        cout << "SDL init failed." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    cout << "SDL Init succeeded." << endl;

    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```