# Compiling c++ with SDL2 in terminal

Tags: c++, g++, sdl, sdl-2

I have been unable to compile a basic class file to generate a window using SDL2, using both brew and compiling from the SDL site using using...

```
 #include <SDL2/SDL.h>
```

at the top of the file.

Have also used...

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include "SDL"
```

among others and nearly always get this error

> ```
> ./src/window.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'SDL2/SDL.h' file not found
> #include <SDL2/SDL.h>
> ```

Something should have worked and just hasn't.

Comment: Please check my answer here, it's related to Xcode but the `sdl-config` part is the same, since you need to add the include path for compiling and the library for linking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016258/using-homebrew-installed-sdl2-with-xcode/28016333#28016333

Comment: Compiler Command? Are you using the proper linker flags? The linker flag you need is probably `-lsdl2`.

Comment: Passing `'sdl2-config --cflags --libs'` to g++ worked for me.

Comment: The code compiles using `'sdl2-config --cflags --libs'` but using that and linking the object file in one step, when running the output simply outputs `Killed: 9`.

If I run the compile and linking stages separate however it seems to be unable to find the SDL files again stating there are undefined symbols and a list of the SDL functions.