# Install SDL2 in mac

Tags: macos, opengl, sdl-2

I am just getting started with learning OpenGL. I am struggling to setup my environment. This is what I did do far:

- Downloaded SDL2 binary from https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php for mac.
- Copied SDL2.framework into ~/Library/Frameworks. This didn't work (copied my command bellow).
- Then I tried to copy SDL2.framework into /System/Library/Frameworks. However I am not not being able to enable write permission there. It's my personal mac. I'm not sure whats going on. I tried to copy it with "sudo ~/Downloads/SDL* /System/Library/Framework" but it didn't work

I am using following command to compile a simple opengl code:

```
g++ test.cpp glad/glad.c -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers -F/Library/Frameworks -framework SDL2
```

[image]

Can someone please help me out ? Not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Shouldn't your paths use `~/Library/Frameworks` instead of `/Library/Frameworks` ? The first refers to your home directory, the other to your root directory...

Comment: You can't modify /System/Library, it's protected by [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899)

Comment: I would suggest a different tack: see the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016258.

Answer (score 20):

```
brew install SDL2

brew install SDL2_image

brew install SDL2_ttf
```

Comment: I came here searching for how to upgrade SDL2. You can do so like this: `brew upgrade sdl2`

Comment: Can you explain what you mean and why? ^^ I've never heard that using Homebrew was very bad.

Comment: I'm a mac user. I cloned https://github.com/aminosbh/sdl2-ttf-sample. And I followed the instructions given there. I had done "brew install sdl2", but  got an error.  The instructions: brew install SDL2_image and  brew install SDL2_ttf
 solved my error! The error was:  CMake Error at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cmake/3.28.2/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message): Could NOT find SDL2 (missing: SDL2_TTF_LIBRARIES SDL2_TTF_INCLUDE_DIRS)...